# Como rellenar una columna segun condiciones

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, funciones, lambda

estoy trabajando un dataframe acerca de valores del ministerio de economia.

Pase todo el dataframe a formato rectangular para poder operarlo facilmente..

Quisiera rellenar una columna de "years" segun un patron,  para el mes "9","10","11","12"(que esta definido en la columna month), quiero que la columna year tenga 2000 y cuando el mes es cualquier otro (o sea, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8) sea 2021
Les muestro lo que hice:

```
import pandas as pd# Libreria que vamos a utilizar para casi cualquier manejo de bases de datos
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt#Libreria para utilizar con todos los graficos
import datetime #Libreria para hacer todo lo que tenga que ver con fechas.

df_mef = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\Cedres\Downloads\Resultados Sector Público - Agosto 2021.xlsx", index_col = 0,sheet_name = "Sector Público Consolidado", skiprows=9).iloc[:, 260:272].dropna()

##Ponemos los meses##

a = ['9','10','11','12','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8']
df_mef.columns = a
df_mef = df_mef.stack().reset_index()
df_mef.columns = ["tipo", "month", "saldo"]
df_mef["month"] = df_mef.month.astype(int)
                                             tipo  month         saldo
0                          RESULTADO PRIMARIO BCU      9    -85.434921
1                          RESULTADO PRIMARIO BCU     10   -101.674900
2                          RESULTADO PRIMARIO BCU     11    -21.967040
3                          RESULTADO PRIMARIO BCU     12   -116.519996
4                          RESULTADO PRIMARIO BCU      1    -74.716914
5                          RESULTADO PRIMARIO BCU      2   -108.686939
6                          RESULTADO PRIMARIO BCU      3   -376.409200
7                          RESULTADO PRIMARIO BCU      4    -85.402780
8                          RESULTADO PRIMARIO BCU      5    580.348444
9                          RESULTADO PRIMARIO BCU      6   -120.713870
10                         RESULTADO PRIMARIO BCU      7   -106.255660
11                         RESULTADO PRIMARIO BCU      8   -121.220060
12                                  Intereses BCU      9    974.817950
13                                  Intereses BCU     10   1707.560720
14                                  Intereses BCU     11  -4415.230600
15                                  Intereses BCU     12   2294.682620
16                                  Intereses BCU      1   2977.278390
17                                  Intereses BCU      2   2107.348430
18                                  Intereses BCU      3   2913.740960
19                                  Intereses BCU      4   1453.967160
20                                  Intereses BCU      5   2503.761840
21                                  Intereses BCU      6   4075.495140
22                                  Intereses BCU      7   2769.545800
23                                  Intereses BCU      8   2277.781820
24                           RESULTADO GLOBAL BCU      9  -1060.252871
25                           RESULTADO GLOBAL BCU     10  -1809.235620
26                           RESULTADO GLOBAL BCU     11   4393.263560
27                           RESULTADO GLOBAL BCU     12  -2411.202616
28                           RESULTADO GLOBAL BCU      1  -3051.995304
29                           RESULTADO GLOBAL BCU      2  -2216.035369
30                           RESULTADO GLOBAL BCU      3  -3290.150160
31                           RESULTADO GLOBAL BCU      4  -1539.369940
32                           RESULTADO GLOBAL BCU      5  -1923.413396
33                           RESULTADO GLOBAL BCU      6  -4196.209010
34                           RESULTADO GLOBAL BCU      7  -2875.801460
35                           RESULTADO GLOBAL BCU      8  -2399.001880
36  RESULTADO PRIMARIO SECTOR PÚBLICO CONSOLIDADO      9   1329.414029
37  RESULTADO PRIMARIO SECTOR PÚBLICO CONSOLIDADO     10  -2082.200043
38  RESULTADO PRIMARIO SECTOR PÚBLICO CONSOLIDADO     11   -902.087054
39  RESULTADO PRIMARIO SECTOR PÚBLICO CONSOLIDADO     12 -18571.924827
40  RESULTADO PRIMARIO SECTOR PÚBLICO CONSOLIDADO      1  16220.627341
41  RESULTADO PRIMARIO SECTOR PÚBLICO CONSOLIDADO      2  -9234.042462
42  RESULTADO PRIMARIO SECTOR PÚBLICO CONSOLIDADO      3 -25924.590912
43  RESULTADO PRIMARIO SECTOR PÚBLICO CONSOLIDADO      4  31921.182677
44  RESULTADO PRIMARIO SECTOR PÚBLICO CONSOLIDADO      5  -6187.704173
45  RESULTADO PRIMARIO SECTOR PÚBLICO CONSOLIDADO      6 -16602.223540
46  RESULTADO PRIMARIO SECTOR PÚBLICO CONSOLIDADO      7  -3840.719049
47  RESULTADO PRIMARIO SECTOR PÚBLICO CONSOLIDADO      8  -3626.307475
48    RESULTADO GLOBAL SECTOR PÚBLICO CONSOLIDADO      9  -3127.401649
49    RESULTADO GLOBAL SECTOR PÚBLICO CONSOLIDADO     10  -7575.557995
50    RESULTADO GLOBAL SECTOR PÚBLICO CONSOLIDADO     11  -4203.937204
51    RESULTADO GLOBAL SECTOR PÚBLICO CONSOLIDADO     12 -30691.774263
52    RESULTADO GLOBAL SECTOR PÚBLICO CONSOLIDADO      1   9650.473275
53    RESULTADO GLOBAL SECTOR PÚBLICO CONSOLIDADO      2 -12678.676736
54    RESULTADO GLOBAL SECTOR PÚBLICO CONSOLIDADO      3 -32855.648179
55    RESULTADO GLOBAL SECTOR PÚBLICO CONSOLIDADO      4  27020.150060
56    RESULTADO GLOBAL SECTOR PÚBLICO CONSOLIDADO      5  -7506.270529
57    RESULTADO GLOBAL SECTOR PÚBLICO CONSOLIDADO      6 -28918.886557
58    RESULTADO GLOBAL SECTOR PÚBLICO CONSOLIDADO      7 -12920.114355
59    RESULTADO GLOBAL SECTOR PÚBLICO CONSOLIDADO      8  -7985.333714
##Como rellenamos los años según alguna condicion?##

df_mef["year"] = [None]*len(df_mef)
eventType = list(df_mef["month"].values)

                                             tipo  month         saldo  year
0                          RESULTADO PRIMARIO BCU      9    -85.434921  None
1                          RESULTADO PRIMARIO BCU     10   -101.674900  None
2                          RESULTADO PRIMARIO BCU     11    -21.967040  None
3                          RESULTADO PRIMARIO BCU     12   -116.519996  None
4                          RESULTADO PRIMARIO BCU      1    -74.716914  None
5                          RESULTADO PRIMARIO BCU      2   -108.686939  None
6                          RESULTADO PRIMARIO BCU      3   -376.409200  None
7                          RESULTADO PRIMARIO BCU      4    -85.402780  None
8                          RESULTADO PRIMARIO BCU      5    580.348444  None
9                          RESULTADO PRIMARIO BCU      6   -120.713870  None
10                         RESULTADO PRIMARIO BCU      7   -106.255660  None
11                         RESULTADO PRIMARIO BCU      8   -121.220060  None
12                                  Intereses BCU      9    974.817950  None
13                                  Intereses BCU     10   1707.560720  None
14                                  Intereses BCU     11  -4415.230600  None
15                                  Intereses BCU     12   2294.682620  None
16                                  Intereses BCU      1   2977.278390  None
17                                  Intereses BCU      2   2107.348430  None
18                                  Intereses BCU      3   2913.740960  None
19                                  Intereses BCU      4   1453.967160  None
20                                  Intereses BCU      5   2503.761840  None
21                                  Intereses BCU      6   4075.495140  None
22                                  Intereses BCU      7   2769.545800  None
23                                  Intereses BCU      8   2277.781820  None
24                           RESULTADO GLOBAL BCU      9  -1060.252871  None
25                           RESULTADO GLOBAL BCU     10  -1809.235620  None
26                           RESULTADO GLOBAL BCU     11   4393.263560  None
27                           RESULTADO GLOBAL BCU     12  -2411.202616  None
28                           RESULTADO GLOBAL BCU      1  -3051.995304  None
29                           RESULTADO GLOBAL BCU      2  -2216.035369  None
30                           RESULTADO GLOBAL BCU      3  -3290.150160  None
31                           RESULTADO GLOBAL BCU      4  -1539.369940  None
32                           RESULTADO GLOBAL BCU      5  -1923.413396  None
33                           RESULTADO GLOBAL BCU      6  -4196.209010  None
34                           RESULTADO GLOBAL BCU      7  -2875.801460  None
35                           RESULTADO GLOBAL BCU      8  -2399.001880  None
36  RESULTADO PRIMARIO SECTOR PÚBLICO CONSOLIDADO      9   1329.414029  None
37  RESULTADO PRIMARIO SECTOR PÚBLICO CONSOLIDADO     10  -2082.200043  None
38  RESULTADO PRIMARIO SECTOR PÚBLICO CONSOLIDADO     11   -902.087054  None
39  RESULTADO PRIMARIO SECTOR PÚBLICO CONSOLIDADO     12 -18571.924827  None
40  RESULTADO PRIMARIO SECTOR PÚBLICO CONSOLIDADO      1  16220.627341  None
41  RESULTADO PRIMARIO SECTOR PÚBLICO CONSOLIDADO      2  -9234.042462  None
42  RESULTADO PRIMARIO SECTOR PÚBLICO CONSOLIDADO      3 -25924.590912  None
43  RESULTADO PRIMARIO SECTOR PÚBLICO CONSOLIDADO      4  31921.182677  None
44  RESULTADO PRIMARIO SECTOR PÚBLICO CONSOLIDADO      5  -6187.704173  None
45  RESULTADO PRIMARIO SECTOR PÚBLICO CONSOLIDADO      6 -16602.223540  None
46  RESULTADO PRIMARIO SECTOR PÚBLICO CONSOLIDADO      7  -3840.719049  None
47  RESULTADO PRIMARIO SECTOR PÚBLICO CONSOLIDADO      8  -3626.307475  None
48    RESULTADO GLOBAL SECTOR PÚBLICO CONSOLIDADO      9  -3127.401649  None
49    RESULTADO GLOBAL SECTOR PÚBLICO CONSOLIDADO     10  -7575.557995  None
50    RESULTADO GLOBAL SECTOR PÚBLICO CONSOLIDADO     11  -4203.937204  None
51    RESULTADO GLOBAL SECTOR PÚBLICO CONSOLIDADO     12 -30691.774263  None
52    RESULTADO GLOBAL SECTOR PÚBLICO CONSOLIDADO      1   9650.473275  None
53    RESULTADO GLOBAL SECTOR PÚBLICO CONSOLIDADO      2 -12678.676736  None
54    RESULTADO GLOBAL SECTOR PÚBLICO CONSOLIDADO      3 -32855.648179  None
55    RESULTADO GLOBAL SECTOR PÚBLICO CONSOLIDADO      4  27020.150060  None
56    RESULTADO GLOBAL SECTOR PÚBLICO CONSOLIDADO      5  -7506.270529  None
57    RESULTADO GLOBAL SECTOR PÚBLICO CONSOLIDADO      6 -28918.886557  None
58    RESULTADO GLOBAL SECTOR PÚBLICO CONSOLIDADO      7 -12920.114355  None
59    RESULTADO GLOBAL SECTOR PÚBLICO CONSOLIDADO      8  -7985.333714  None

x = None
def event(n):
    global x

    if n == "9" or "10" or "11" or "12":
        x = 2020
    elif n == "1" or "2" or "3" or "4" or "5" or "6" or "7" or "8":
        x = 2021
    else:
        x = x
        
    return x
state1 = list(map(lambda n: event(n), eventType))
state 1
[2020,
 2020,
 2020,
 2020,
 2020,
 2020,
 2020,
 2020,
 2020,
 2020,
 2020,
 2020,
 2020,
 2020,
 2020,
 2020,
 2020,
 2020,
 2020,
 2020,
 2020,
 2020,
 2020,
 2020,
 2020,
 2020,
 2020,
 2020,
 2020,
 2020,
 2020,
 2020,
 2020,
 2020,
 2020,
 2020,
 2020,
 2020,
 2020,
 2020,
 2020,
 2020,
 2020,
 2020,
 2020,
 2020,
 2020,
 2020,
 2020,
 2020,
 2020,
 2020,
 2020,
 2020,
 2020,
 2020,
 2020,
 2020,
 2020,
 2020]
df_mef["year"] = pd.Series(state1)
```

Todo va bien hasta ahi pero cuando uso la funcion lamba, en vez de rellenarme como quiero me rellena todo 2020 por algun motivo que no identifico.

El df es el siguiente: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17yGrdgzb-Sba1b8V5_Ovg5PrSFxnMjxW/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=104892511677427503963&rtpof=true&sd=true

nota: mi interes esta de los datos septiembre 2020 a agosto 2021 de Sector Publico consolidado, los datos ya quedan seleccionados cuando importo de pandas.

Comment: Cual es la condición?, no me quedó claro

Comment: El link del df esta subido a drive y se puede bajar ( esta el link en el post) pero sino ahora lo edito y muestro!, disculpa

Comment: Aunque sospecho que el problema están en los ifs que tienes dentro de la función `event`. Cámbialo a `if n in ['9', '10', '11', '12`]` y `elif n in "12345678"`

Comment: como otra sugerencia, puedes usar apply así `df_mef["year"] = df_mef["year"].apply(lambda x: event(x))`

Comment: Nono, los datos estan tomados de forma de tomar agosto y los ultimos 12 meses, es decir sep 2020 - agosto 2021, seria 2020 del  mes 9 hasta mes 12, y luego del mes 1 al mes 8 2021

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que la lógica para rellenar el año sea: 2020 si el mes es de septiembre a diciembre (ambos inclusive) o 2021 si el mes es de enero a agosto (ambos inclusive), tu función `event()` está mal.

Para empezar estás usando cadenas para representar los meses (`"1"`, `"2"`, etc) cuando en realidad la columna del mes contenía datos de tipo entero.

Además estás cayendo en un error muy común que es querer comparar con varios valores usando `or` de esta forma:

```
if n == 1 or 2 or 3 ...
```

cuando debería ser:

```
if n == 1 or n == 2 or n == 3 ...
```

Pero hay una forma mucho más compacta de escribirlo:

```
def event(n):
    if n in range(9,13):   # range() deja fuera el extremo derecho
        x = 2020
    elif n in range(1, 10):
        x = 2021
    else:
        x = x
    return x
```

Por otro lado, no necesitas una lambda ni crear previamente una columna rellena de None, ni la variable intermedia `eventType`. Puedes simplificar tu código así:

```
df_mef = pd.read_excel(r"Resultados Sector Público - Agosto 2021.xlsx", index_col = 0,sheet_name = "Sector Público Consolidado", skiprows=9).iloc[:, 260:272].dropna()

##Ponemos los meses##
a = ['9','10','11','12','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8']
df_mef.columns = a
df_mef = df_mef.stack().reset_index()
df_mef.columns = ["tipo", "month", "saldo"]
df_mef["month"] = df_mef.month.astype(int)

##Como rellenamos los años según alguna condicion?##
df_mef["year"] = pd.Series(event(n) for n in df_mef["month"])
```

Comment: Me sirvio!, muchisimas gracias jaja